# My Skyrim crashes when I fast travel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I play on Xbox 360 and I've recently restarted my game. I'm not far in the game yet. (Only completed the first dragon fight quest). I'm currently at Riverwood and whenever I fast travel, the loading screen will be there for about 10 seconds then it completely freeze for ages. It happens also when I turn my Xbox back on after turning it all off. Should I delete some saves?

Comment: Does this happen with all your save files, or just your latest one?

Comment: Just the latest one.

Comment: Since it doesn't happen on your previous saves, it makes me think that it's not a memory issue. Nevertheless, it's worth trying to clear your system cache. If that doesn't work, I would suggest running from Riverwood to someplace else (like Whiterun), then see if the fast-travel problem still occurs. If it does, my last resort would be to delete some old saves -- but _only_ if you have a very large number of them. If none of the aforementioned suggestions work, reverting to your second most-recent save is likely your only option.

Answer (score -1):

I would free up space by deleting saves. Also make sure you have enough mb and gb to play game. If it still doesn't work then I suggest getting a horse to travel a bit faster.